# Gruntfile.js grunt-contrib-uglify not found

Tags: gruntjs

I'm new to grunt and still finding my feet.

I have grunt installed and uglify with

```
npm install grunt-contrib-uglify --save-dev
```

I have the following in the gruntfile.js to test minifying css files

```
  // Code example 01-minify
  module.exports = function(grunt) {

  // Load the plugin that provides the "uglify" task.
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');

  // Project configuration.
  grunt.initConfig({
    uglify: {
        target1: {
            src: 'styles.css',
            dest: 'styles.min.css'
        }
    }
  });
  // Define the default task
  grunt.registerTask('default', ['uglify']);
  };
```

If I run `grunt`, I get

```
  Local Npm module "grunt-contrib-uglify" not found. Is it installed?
  Warning: Task "uglify" not found. Use --force to continue.
```

Comment: Did you run "npm install ..." in the same folder as your gruntfile? Is there a node_modules folder in that location?